# Access value outside of for-loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

### Hi!

By iterating through nested json-files I'm using this function:

```
function buildPeopleGroups(People, container, parentObject) {
    _.each(People, function (item) {

        var peopleGuid =[];
        for (var peopleIterator= 0; peopleIterator< People.length; peopleIterator++) {
            peopleGuid [peopleIterator] = People[peopleIterator].Id
        }
        var newContainer;
        item.parent = parentObject;
        //switch different people
        switchPeople(item.Name, parentObject, peopleGuid [peopleIterator]);
        if (item.People) buildPeopleGroups(item.People, container, item);
    });
};
```

But this doesnt work... The 'peopleGuid [peopleIterator]'-attribute is out of scope and cannot be accessed outside of the for-loop. Now how can I easily put this value into the 'switchPeople'-function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `peopleIterator` used in the function `switchPeople` will always be equals to `People.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 var peopleGuid =[];
    for (var peopleIterator= 0; peopleIterator< People.length; peopleIterator++) {
        peopleGuid.push({peopleIterator:People[peopleIterator].Id});
    }
 console.log('peopleGuid',peopleGuid);
```